# Find all solutions to $a^{2003} \equiv 1 \mod{17}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Through messing around with numbers, I found that $a \equiv 1\mod{17}$. How would you obtain this answer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

An idea:

$$2003=16\cdot{125}+3\implies a^{2003}=\left(a^{16}\right)^{125}a^3=a^3\pmod{17}\;\text{(why?)}$$

Thus, doing arithmetic modulo $\;17\;$ all the way, we get:

$$a^3=1\iff (a-1)(a^2+a+1)=0$$

But the discriminant of the above quadratic is

$$\Delta=1^2-4=-3=14\;,\;\;\text{and}\;\;\binom{14}{17}=\binom 2{17}\binom7{17}\stackrel{\text{Quad. Recip.}}=1\cdot\binom37=-1$$

so the quadratic doesn't have roots modulo $\;17\;$ and the only solution indeed is $\;a=1\;$ .

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ {\rm mod}\ 17\!:\ a^{\large\color{#0a0}{2003}}\equiv 1\!\overset{\rm Fermat}{\equiv}\! a^{\large \color{#c00}{16}}\,$ so the order of $\,a\,$ divides $\,\overbrace{\color{#0a0}{2003},\color{#c00}{16}}^{\rm coprime}\,$ so it is $\,1,\,$ thus $\,a \equiv 1.$

**Remark** $\ $ Here is an additive analog: a rational number is an integer if it can be written in two ways with *coprime* denominators, i.e. $\,a/b = c/d\,$ and $\,\gcd(b,d) = 1$ $\Rightarrow$ $\,a/b\in\Bbb Z.$ Indeed, the least denominator is a common divisor of every denominator so a common divisor of $\,b,d\,$ so it is $\,1.$

The key structure at the heart of the matter is clarified by study of group theory and ideal theory, particularly *cyclic* groups and PIDs = *principal* ideal domains (e.g. domains possessing a Euclidean algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use Fermat's "little" theorem to reduce $2003$ to something more manageable.

Comment: He's done that.

Comment: It's not clear which equation is "this".

Comment: That's true, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your problem by using Fermat's little theorem; for $17\nmid a$, $a^{16} \equiv 1\; (\textrm{mod}\; 17)$. Since $2003 = 125\cdot16+3$, we are looking for $a$ with

$$a^{2003} = (a^{16})^{125}\cdot a^3 \equiv a^3 \equiv 1\; (\textrm{mod}\; 17)$$

This is much easier...

Answer (score 1):

Fermat's Little Theorem tells you that if $a$ is not divisible by $17$ then $a^{16} \equiv 1$.

Next we note that $(16,2003)=1$ which implies that we can find integers $p,q$ with $16p+2003q=1$

Now we have $$a=a^{16p+2003q}=(a^{16})^p\cdot (a^{2003})^q\equiv 1^p\cdot 1^q=1$$

Comment: Note that this adds an idea to some of the other suggestions and in this form invites generalisation, because the dependence on the special numbers $17, 2003$ is reduced to a minimum.

Comment: It is even simpler using the concept of *order* - see my answer.

Comment: @BillDubuque: I agree that order is the right concept. I think the development of order as a viable concept is essentially equivalent to the reasoning I have illustrated. I trust OP will follow the stepping stones to the "right" way of seeing things ...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $a\equiv b\pmod n$ means that $a-b=kn,k\in\mathbb{Z}$. So, $a\equiv 1\pmod{17}$ means that $a-1=17k,k\in\mathbb{Z}$.